# What is wrong with declaration variable in function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to declare function and pass variable `fixed_cost = 0  IN INT`  something like

```
FUNCTION GET_ALL_ENABLED_ACC(fixed_cost IN INT)
```

So the point is to declare fixed_cost and initialize value to `0` but I ge error

```
Error(37,16): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following:     . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between using || multiset member submultiset The symbol " " was ignored.
```

I try something like

```
 fixed_cost : = 0 IN INT
```

AND

```
fixed_cost  =: 0 IN INT
```

Also I try to change INT to NUMBER  and after `BEGIN` initialize value but doesn't work.

```
FUNCTION GET_ALL_ENABLED_ACC(fixed_cost NUMBER)
 RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
OPEN rc FOR
    fixed_cost  = 0;
    SELECT Number_ FROM accounting_plan WHERE Enabled = 1 AND FixedCost = fixed_cost;
RETURN rc;
END  GET_ALL_ENABLED_ACC;
```

What should I do in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be `FUNCTION GET_ALL_ENABLED_ACC(fixed_cost IN INT:=0)` or `FUNCTION GET_ALL_ENABLED_ACC(fixed_cost IN INT default 0)`